# Not able to set lang to CN in zsh macOS, but locale is good. The word “total” is still shown in English

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, locale, oh-my-zsh

**~/.zshrc**:

```
export LANG="zh_CN.UTF-8"
export LANGUAGE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
export LC_COLLATE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
export LC_MESSAGES="zh_CN.UTF-8"
export LC_MONETARY="zh_CN.UTF-8"
export LC_NUMERIC="zh_CN.UTF-8"
export LC_TIME="zh_CN.UTF-8"
export LC_ALL="zh_CN.UTF-8"
```

**terminal**

```
$ locale  
LANG="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="zh_CN.UTF-8"

$ locale -a                                                         
en_NZ
nl_NL.UTF-8
pt_BR.UTF-8
fr_CH.ISO8859-15
eu_ES.ISO8859-15
en_US.US-ASCII
af_ZA
bg_BG
cs_CZ.UTF-8
fi_FI
**zh_CN.UTF-8**
eu_ES
sk_SK.ISO8859-2
...
```

**Appearence**

```
$ ll                                                                     
total 69760
drwx------@   9 groovewjh  staff             288B  2 24 13:25 Applications
drwxr-xr-x@   4 groovewjh  _analyticsusers   128B  2  9 13:08 Applications (Parallels)
...
```

But the word “**total**” should be a Chinese word, The prompt without any function has been changed to Chinese.

I don't know much about the mechanism behind this. I haven't found an answer to this question in the Chinese community, and I hope to find an answer here.

I've tried to set these code in **~/.zprofile** , but doesn't work, still.

```
export LANG="zh_CN.UTF-8"
export LANGUAGE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
export LC_COLLATE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
export LC_MESSAGES="zh_CN.UTF-8"
export LC_MONETARY="zh_CN.UTF-8"
export LC_NUMERIC="zh_CN.UTF-8"
export LC_TIME="zh_CN.UTF-8"
export LC_ALL="zh_CN.UTF-8"
```

Comment: According to a comment on [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/110637), very few command-line utilities on macOS are compiled with international support, beyond changing date formats and such. They explicitly cite `/usr/bin/cal` as one of the few programs that can handle multiple languages, and on my system `cal` does display Chinese characters. The post is from several years ago, but apparently it still applies.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
 If I have time, I will continue to review relevant information. 
Thank you very much.